# Can't Get UFW Firewall to Allow Anything

Tags: firewall, ufw

I'm trying to set UFW (using GUFW) to create a firewall that only allows network connections when OpenVPN is connected.

So in GUFW I deny incoming and outgoing connections and enable the Firewall. I then create a rule that allows incoming/outgoing of the openvpn service.

Interestingly, with these settings I'm able to make a VPN connection using Network Connections, however **I'm unable to browse**. Note that without these rules I'm unable to make the VPN connection.

I've also tried creating a rule using the OpenVPN ports and VPN IP address with no success.

To troubleshoot, I delete those rules and create more broad rules of allowing incoming/outgoing HTTP and HTTPS. With these rules in place, I'm still unable to browse online. I tried this while creating rules with my IP address, and no luck.

Here's an example of my current rules, which is not allowing me to browse.

```
user1@vuser-pc1:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Edit: If I set "allow" outgoing, and then create rules to disallow http/https connections, the rules work. I cannot browse. It is strange to me that in this case the rules work to disallow, but I can't get it to allow.

Answer (score 0):

It's because a browser is changing the port:
Try this for know the port:

```
netstat -anp | grep
```

But it's changing a lot (in my case).

Similar inverse problem: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/106974

Comment: But if I set the firewall rules not based on Port but on IP, it still doesn't work.